# Determine the values of a long list which are not existing in a postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Provided there is a long list of values, which happen to be values of attributes of records in a postgres-database.

I would like to create a query which finds out which of these values can not be found in the database.

I have no right to execute DDL-Statements and I would like to avoid procedural code.

Example:

the table might be

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
   ID Integer,
   attr varchar(30)
)
```

The list might be something like (but longer, about 240000 values)

```
ATTR
TestValue0
TestValue1
TestValue2
TestValue3
```

Using sed I can create and execute a statement

```
select count(*) from Test where attr in ('TestValue0', 
                'TestValue1','TestValue2','TestValue3')
```

This statement shows me, that not all of these values can be found in Test.

How can I formulate a query which tells me which of these uniq-values can not be found in the postgres-database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want to do, you can use `left join`, `not in` or `not exists`.  But the key is that you need a derived table with the values you care about:

```
select v.attr
from (values ('TestValue0'),  ('TestValue1'), ('TestValue2'), ('TestValue3')
     ) v attr
where not exists (select 1 from test t where t.attr = v.attr);
```

Comment: Thank you, strangely the left join is much faster than the subselect